# I'm looking for an accounting software than can be locally hosted and can be integrated with SugarCRM or PHP

Tags: windows, open-source, php, accounting

It would be better if it is a paid software as they offer better support, I already looked up Xero and QuickBooks but they are cloud hosted and cannot be hosted locally.

The features we need are:

- **Can create:**

  - Sales Journal
  - Cash Receipts Journal
  - Purchase Journal
  - Check Disbursement Journal
  - General Journal
- **Can Handle:**

  - Cashflow : Dashboard, File Storage, Inventory, Multi-Currency Accounting, Search
  - Invoicing : Quotes, Invoice Reminders
  - Reports : Financial Reporting, Fixed Assets, Business Performance Dashboard

> Should be self-hosted. Track Sales, Expenses, Payments, Accounts
>   Receivable, and Remaining Balance.

**Reports:**

- Income per lead source (overall)
- Income per Product (overall)
- Accounts Receivable by Invoices (by age: 30 days, 60 days)
- Life Time Value of Account (amount) (overall)
- Sales (overall)
- Payment (overall)

Basically, anything similar to [Xero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xero_(software)) or [QuickBooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickbooks) but can be locally hosted.

Comment: I don't mind it at all, thanks for the assistance as well :)

Comment: You're welcome! If, while skimming the links at the end of those Wikipedia pages, you find some matching product: also be welcome to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: Note that if you ever think you'll need outside accounting help, the choice of accounting software may limit your ability to get outsiders quickly up to speed. Most contract bookeepers/accountants know QuickBooks, for instance, but may fumble a bit with other solutions.